# Как правильно рассчитать разницу во времени

Tags: c#, время

Использую для получении времени`DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;`

```
string a=  curDate.ToLongDateString();  //Результат: a= "06.03.2014 14:10:00"
```

Как правильно рассчитать сколько прошло времени между двумя точками?
Конкретно узнать, что не прошло 23 часа.

Comment: Отнять от первой даты вторую?

Comment: это понятно ,а если со временем (это важно)